# Automate ASP.NET login form by automatically populating credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an existing Login.aspx page that works when a user manually populates their login credentials and submits them.

I would like to create another version of this form for 'TRIAL' purposes that automatically populates the username and password textbox fields with values. I would like to make these textbox controls hidden. So essentially user just hits login button, it uses the automatically populated values, and logs the user in.

How can I convert existing code to do this?

Here is the code with the two textbox controls for username and password:

```
<asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName"
Text="Username">
</asp:Label>

<asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CustomValidator ID="UserNameRequired" ValidateEmptyText="True"
OnServerValidate="ValidateUserName" ClientValidationFunction=""
runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName"
ErrorMessage="<%$ resources: UserNameRequired %>" 
ToolTip="<%$ resources: UserNameRequired %>" ValidationGroup="sLogin"
Text="<%$ resources: asterisk %>">
</asp:CustomValidator>

<asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password"
Text="<%$ resources: Password %>" Style="margin-top: 5px;"></asp:Label>

<asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" CssClass="editCtl"
TextMode="Password" AutoComplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
```

I realize I can simply add the values directly into the page like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" Text="user1" style="display:none;"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" CssClass="editCtl" AutoComplete="off" Text="password1" style="display:none;"></asp:TextBox>
```

However, I guess the REAL question would then be how do I call these values in a more secure way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your OP I am making the following assumptions: You have two login pages, one for the normal users and one for the trial users.  Both of these .ASPX pages are sharing the same code behind page in order to share the logic.  This results in the trial login page needing to supply the username and password without the user entering it, and you don’t want those easily visible to the user.

You can use a second submit button for the trial login.  On the normal page the trial submit button would be hidden and on the trial page the username, password and normal submit is hidden.

Refactor the code behind page so the login logic is in a separate method.  For the normal login page get the username and password from the UI controls and call the method.  In the trial button click use hard coded values, or better yet configured values, and call the method.

Answer (score 0):

What about store the data, encoded into a cookie, and fill the input value if this cookie exist?

> C#

```
Response.Cookies["userName"].Value = "patrick";
Response.Cookies["userName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
```

> VB

```
Response.Cookies("userName").Value = "patrick"
Response.Cookies("userName").Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
```